# Excel, using the answers from two drop down lists to get do a calculation

Tags: excel

I have a cell which has a drop down list of 4 classifications (Installer, Foreman, Superintendent, Project Manager) and a second corresponding cell with a drop down list of 3 (Standard, OT X 1.5, OT X 2).  Id like a calculation to be made depending on what my selections are. for example Foreman at OT X 2, would be $100).  I want to make this an excel template so if there is adjustments i should make so the calculations will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what it is you want but offer the following as at least a possible 'kick off' point:

[image: SO18774693 example]

There is Data Validation on A1 based on the list in G2:G5 and in B1 based on H1:J1.